# QCA9377 not coming up with ath10k

Tags: linux, usb, driver

**Device Model : Linksys WUSB6100M |
Kernel : 4.14.0-rc5-wt-ath+, 4.2 |
Backports version : 4.14-rc4, 4.14-rc5**

Kernel Source : https://github.com/erstrom/linux-ath

Am trying to bringup the above specified USB card with ath10k driver. After reading the FW files am getting the following logs.

[ 6218.904243] usb 2-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 14 using ehci-pci

[ 6219.014440] usb 2-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=13b1, idProduct=0042

[ 6219.014446] usb 2-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, 
SerialNumber=3

[ 6219.014450] usb 2-1.4: Product: USBWLAN

[ 6219.014454] usb 2-1.4: Manufacturer: Qualcomm Atheros

[ 6219.014457] usb 2-1.4: SerialNumber: 12345678

[ 6219.015314] usb 2-1.4: WARNING: ath10k USB support is incomplete, don't expect anything to work!

[ 6219.015672] usb 2-1.4: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-usb-2-1.4.bin failed with error -2

[ 6219.015695] usb 2-1.4: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-usb-2-1.4.bin failed with error -2

[ 6219.016134] usb 2-1.4: qca9377 hw1.1 target 0x05020001 chip_id 0x00000000 sub 0000:0000

[ 6219.016138] usb 2-1.4: kconfig debug 1 debugfs 1 tracing 0 dfs 0 testmode 0

[ 6219.017441] usb 2-1.4: firmware ver WLAN.TF.1.0-00002-QCATFSWPZ-5 api 6 features ignore-otp crc32 c3e0d04f

[ 6219.055734] usb 2-1.4: board_file api 1 bmi_id N/A crc32 544289f7

[ 6221.308242] usb 2-1.4: Service connect timeout

[ 6221.308252] usb 2-1.4: Invalid resp message ID 0x1

[ 6221.308257] usb 2-1.4: failed to connect htt (-71)

[ 6221.412265] usb 2-1.4: could not init core (-71)

[ 6221.412358] usb 2-1.4: could not probe fw (-71)

If anyone experienced and fixed this issue please share the details.

Else if anyone aware of the driver and kernel version please suggest that.

Thanks ,
Vikas